# How to get sender widget with a signal/slot mechanism?

Tags: qt4, qt-signals

It's possible to bind more than one signal to one slot (isn't?). So, is there a way to understand which widget sends the signal? I'm looking for something like `sender` argument of events in .NET

Answer (score 94, accepted):

[`QObject::sender()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) will do the job.

Answer (score 144):

Use [`QObject::sender()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender) in the slot, like in the following Example:

```
void MainWindow::someSetupFunction( void )
{
   ...
   connect( _foobarButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonPressedSlot()) );
}

void MainWindow::buttonPressedSlot()
{
   // e.g. check with member variable _foobarButton
   QObject* obj = sender();
   if( obj == _foobarButton )
   { 
      ...
   }

   // e.g. casting to the class you know its connected with
   QPushButton* button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
   if( button != NULL ) 
   { 
      ...
   }

}
```

Comment: isn't qobject_cast better than plain dynamic_cast?

Comment: @elephant Yes, as desribed on http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/metaobjects.html . This should be improved in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can connect multiple signals to one slot. In this case you would use `QSignalMapper` to differentiate the sources of the signals. This solution is limited to parameterless signals. You can see an example [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#advanced-signals-and-slots-usage).