# Refer to the Sender Object in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having some trouble, I'm fairly new to Qt and C++ and was testing the waters so to say. Ill try to describe my problem as follows. I have a LineEdit `QLineEdit` and this edit has a connection which looks like this:

`connect(my_lineedit, SIGNAL (textEdited(QString)),this, SLOT (handleEdits()));`

The `handleEdits()` method gets called and does the following:

1. Disconnect the previous Signal from `my_lineedit`
2. Create a new `QLineEdit` which gets a new signal and calls `handleAddedEdits()`
3. Adds the newely created Edit to my layout.

The stated above works fine Im just telling you this so you get the picture.
Now in the new method which I called `handleAddedEdits()` I want kinda the same procedure to happen again.

1. Disconnect the Signal which calls `handleAddedEdits()` from the Edit which invoked this method in the first place.
2. Create a fresh `QLineEdit`
3. Add this to my layout.

The problem is: in the first case `my_lineedit` is declared in my class so I can freely refer to it and and remove the signal as I wish. In the second case I have a `QLineEdit` which was created dynamically in the `handleEdits()` method and is the "Sender". My Question is, how can I refer to the "Sender Object" ro remove the Signal from the dynamically created edit?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046839/how-to-get-sender-widget-with-a-signal-slot-mechanism).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [`QObject::sender()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) method in your receiver's slot:

> For cases where you may require information on the sender of the
>   signal, Qt provides the `QObject::sender()` function, which returns a
>   pointer to the object that sent the signal.

```
handleAddedEdits()
{
    QObject* obj = sender();
    disconnect( obj, SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), 0, 0 );
    //...
}
```

Comment: That works! Just out of interest: can I actually recast the QObject to QLineEdit in this case since it is a QLineEdit?

Comment: @Vollmilchbb, Yes, you can use [`qobject_cast`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast): `QLineEdit *edit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(obj);`