# C++ Qt: is it possible to create a sort of template slot?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt and not a C++ expert so please bear with me with this one.
I'm working on an application that has 12 different QPushButtons, but all of them perform very similar actions: they grab some value from a map and then use it to set the style for that button:

```
void MainWindow::on_btn01_clicked(){
    QString img=images["btn01"];
    ui->btn01->setStyleSheet("#btn01{ background-image: url(://" + img + ") }");
}
```

For each one of the 12 buttons I have to create a slot that only differs in the button being used. So it looks a bit weird to create 12 functions that are almost identical.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one more simple method, that is set the `QPushButton`'s object name respectively, and check the Object name in your slot and use that string. This saves you a lot of code.

Ex:
QPushButton 1 object name is set as `button->setObjectName("btn01");` and respectively you can set the other names of the buttons and in your slot you could do some thing like this

```
void MainWindow::on_button_clicked(){
     QPushButton* btn=qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender()); 
     QString name=btn->objectName(); 
     QString img=images[name]; btn->setStyleSheet("#" + name + "{ background-image: url(://" + img + ");
}
```

and then connect all your `QPushButtons` to this slot

Comment: I was able to get a similar approach working (changed a few things, as I kept getting an error about QPushButton trying to be cast to QString). First connected all my buttons to the slot in the constructor: `connect(ui->btn01, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_button_clicked()));` and did this once per button (not sure if there would be a way to avoid calling it 12 times). Then I implemented the slot as: `QPushButton* btn=qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender()); QString name=btn->objectName(); QString img=images[name]; btn->setStyleSheet("#" + name + "{ background-image: url(://" + img + ") }");`

Answer (score 5):

Generally, there are several approaches I've seen used:

1. **The preferred method: lambda expressions.**

   If you're using modern C++ (C++11 or newer), you can use [a lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627218/3126098) to get the exact effect you described.

   I'd expect the resulting code to look something like this:

   ```
   foreach( QPushButton * button : buttons ) {
     connect( button, &QPushButton::clicked, [button, &images]() {
       button->setStyleSheet( QString( "{ background-image: url(://%1) }" )
         .arg( images[button->objectName()] ) );
     });
   }
   ```

   See "[Qt Slots and C++11 lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19721153/3126098)" for more guidance on how to write lambda functions with Qt.
2. A dirtier way: QObject::sender().

   Qt lets you use [QObject::sender()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) within a slot to get a pointer to the object that invoked it. This has been a widely used approach for many years, but there are limitations, as described in the Qt documentation:

   > Warning: As mentioned above, the return value of this function is not valid when the slot is called via a Qt::DirectConnection from a thread different from this object's thread. Do not use this function in this type of scenario.

   See "[How to get sender widget with a signal/slot mechanism?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18785558/3126098)" for more information.
3. Obsolete code: QSignalMapper.

   There's a [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html) class that will let you associate a signal with a bit of data, like a string, to then connect to a slot that uses this parameter. This used to exist as a convenience class in Qt but is being phased out because the lambda methodology makes it pointless.

   If you need to update code that uses QSignalMapper to remove it, [this tutorial](https://evileg.com/en/post/159/) is a reasonable starting point.

Comment: If you absolutely cannot use C++11, the deprecated and obsolete [QSignalMapper][1] was created for this. However, it is discouraged from being used in new code and I think you'd be hard pressed to find a platform that supports Qt5, but not C++11.


  [1]: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html