# Is there a way to know which signal triggered slot in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Assume that i have two signals (`void signal1()` and `void signal2()`) and one slot (`void slot()`).
Both signals are connected to the slot:

```
connect(this, &Classname::signal1, this, &Classname::slot);
connect(this, &Classname::signal2, this, &Classname::slot);
```

In implementation of the `slot()`, is there a way to know which signal triggered this slot?

Comment: Maybe `QObject::senderSignalIndex()` can help?

Comment: If practical, you can use a DirectConnection and then just look at the call stack.

Comment: Possible duplicate [how to get sender widget with a signal slot mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046839/how-to-get-sender-widget-with-a-signal-slot-mechanism)?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but:  if you find yourself needing to know that information, that might be a sign that it's time to redesign your program so that knowing the sending signal is no longer important.  Keeping the signal-sending code and the slot/receiving code blissfully ignorant of each other's existence is useful, because it prevents the code from making assumptions about how it is used... assumptions that would prevent it from being (easily) re-used in other configurations in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go through lambdas that provide the extra info...

```
connect(this, &Classname::signal1, this,
        [source = 1, this]()
        {
            slot(source);
        });
connect(this, &Classname::signal2, this,
        [source = 2, this]()
        {
            slot(source);
        });
```

(The above assumes your current implementation of `Classname::slot` takes no parameters -- adjust to suit.)